# Suggestions for a Small error in lex and yacc

Tags: linux, nlp, yacc, lex

again some problem in the NLP implementation of my code ..
In pro.l file i have a few patterns and their actions ...
Pro.l

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void yyerror(char *str);
%}
%%

[\t] ;
[a-zA-Z]+   { yylval = strdup(yytext) ; return INPUT ; }   /* may be this line is source of error . It has been written so as to include Junk words */
"is equal to"   { return CONDITION ; }
"whose"    { return WHOSE ; }
"by"     { return PREP ; }
"any"    { return QUALIFIER ; }
"our"    { return QUALIFIER ; }
"show"    { return ASK  ; }
"list"    { return ASK ; }
"display us"   { return ASK  ; }
"and"   { return WORD ; } 
"every"  { printf("%s \n", yylval) ; return QUALIFIER  ; }  
"of every"  { return QUALIFIER  ; }
"all"  { printf("%s \n", yylval) ; return QUALIFIER  ; } 
"name"   { yylval = strdup(yytext) ; printf("%s \n", yylval) ; return FIELD ; }
"id"   { yylval = strdup(yytext) ; return FIELD ; }
"the"  { return QUALIFIER  ; }     
"how many"   { return MOJ ; }
"count"   { return MOJ ; }
"book"  { yylval = strdup(yytext) ; printf("%s \n", yylval) ; return TABLE   ; }
"?"   { return EOL ; }
"."   { return EOL ; }
%%
```

The above given is the pro.l and i want to **include a pattern** : `[a-zA-Z]+ action`  but it is not allowing me to do so and gives errors . I want to include this pattern so that that i can accomodate any junk words in my programme .

Below given is pro.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define YYSTYPE char *        
extern char *yytext ;

int yylex(void) ;
static void yyerror(char *str) 
{
    printf("yyerror : %s " , str) ;
}
%}

%error-verbose
%token ASK
%token PREP
%token QUALIFIER
%token MOJ
%token WORD
%token TOTAL
%token EOL 
%token TABLE
%token FIELD
%token WHOSE
%token CONDITION
%token INPUT

%%

translate : select
          | count
          ;                                                                                                                                                   


select : ASK QUALIFIER TABLE EOL    { printf("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM %s",$3) ;} 
       | ASK FIELD QUALIFIER TABLE EOL        { printf("SELECT %s  FROM %s",$2,$4) ;}      
       | ASK QUALIFIER TABLE FIELD EOL  { printf("SELECT DISTINCT %s FROM %s ",$4 ,$3) ;}
       | ASK QUALIFIER FIELD WORD FIELD QUALIFIER TABLE EOL    { printf("SELECT DISTINCT %s , %s FROM %s", $3, $5, $7) ;} 
       | ASK QUALIFIER TABLE WHOSE FIELD CONDITION INPUT EOL    { printf("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM %s WHERE %s =", $3, $5); } 
       |    
       ;

count : MOJ TABLE EOL   { printf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s", $2) ;}
      | ASK TABLE MOJ EOL    { printf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s", $2); } 
      | MOJ TABLE PREP FIELD EOL    {printf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE %s = ",$2 ,$4) ;}
      ;
%%

#include "lex.yy.c"
extern int yylex() ;
extern int yyparse() ;
extern FILE *yyin ;
int main() 
{
    FILE *myfile = fopen("sample.txt" , "r") ;
    if(!myfile)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file ") ;
        return -1 ;
    }
    yyin = myfile ;
    do
    {
        yyparse();
    }while(!feof(yyin)) ;
    yylex_destroy() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Please suggest me some ways to accomodate the junk words not represented in the current patterns of lex file .

Errors stmts : *i/p* -->  display us the book whose name is equal to xyz .

*error* --> yyerror : syntax error , unexpected INPUT , expecting QUALIFIER or TABLE or FIELD .

**P.S.** :  Junk Words like : xyz , abc , fgfhg , jhyjg898 etc

Comment: Welcome on board. Please include any error messages you get, unedited and in full, with your question. Thank you.

Comment: Have included the error in the problem stmt and also the command/pattern that i want to include

Comment: Put the catch-all after the other rules.

Comment: I suppose by catch-all you mean to say i use : <*>. { }    .......  But i want to print this junk value . This rule really did work in ignoring those junk words . But what i want to do is to catch those values in yylval and then print them in yacc file . I doesn't help me do that ( I have also tried printing yytext in those curly brackets of action but doesn't print anything. So there's no way i can assign the value to yylval ) .. Any further suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put `[a-zA-Z]+` (the catch-all of Jonathan) as the first rule. In case of ambiguities lex will take the longest pattern that matches. If two patterns match a string of the same length, then the first one is taken. So by placing the catch-all first, it will also match the other keywords like `whose`. That is why Jonathan said to place this catch-all rule last. That way all keywords will be matched first and only if they don't match the catch-all will be used.